# The Powershell Command "Get-DistributionGroup" doesn't work

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-module

The `Get-DistributionGroup` command is supposed to list distribution groups in a domain but I can't get it to run on my server.

After some Googling I found that `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` needs to be run first, but what I get when I run that is:

> Import-Module : The specified module 'ActiveDirectory' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

My questions are

1. How do I install this module into my PowerShell module directory? I thought it was supposed to do this automatically
2. Once I have it installed, do I just run `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` and then I can run `Get-DistributionGroup` to list my dist groups?

Comment: Installing the AD tools won't help.  Get-DistributionGroup is an Exchange cmdlet. You'll need to install the Exchange Management Tools, or connect to a management session on an Exchange server.

Comment: @mjolinor, that's exactly what I needed to know. I figured something was up. Thanks for the tip, I'll see if I can install that.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing mjolinor's comment, but feel free to append with extra info.

Installing the AD tools won't help. `Get-DistributionGroup` is an Exchange cmdlet.

You'll need to either:

- install the Exchange Management Tools
- or connect to a management session on an Exchange server

Comment: Ok, but how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to exchange, I would follow these steps listed in the Microsoft Docs:

- Installing the management tools, essentially download and mount the
  iso, then run the Setup.exe. Steps are listed [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/post-installation-tasks/install-management-tools?view=exchserver-2019#use-exchange-unattended-setup-mode-to-install-the-exchange-management-tools)
- You can connect to Exchange Online by using Azure SAMI account,
  assigning the appropriate permissions (Exchange Administrator,
  Exchange Recipient Administrator) to the registered app. You can
  follow the steps using the Microsoft Docs [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-exo-powershell-managed-identity?view=exchange-ps)